# Call method with KeyValuePair input argument

Tags: python-3.x, opc-ua

I'm very new to OPU UA, please excuse if this is a very basic question.
I have a method that needs to set 3 arguments. It works well using UaExpert.

UaExpert call method is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0z5K.png)

The input arguments are as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0zO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwBsL.png)

My code as follows

```
        id_types = await client.get_namespace_index(config.NS_TYPES)
        id_core = await client.get_namespace_index(config.NS_CORE)
        machine = await client.nodes.objects.get_child(
            [f"{id_core}:HEIDENHAIN NC", f"{id_core}:Machine"])
        tool_data_methods = await machine.get_child(
            [
                f"{id_types}:ToolDataManagement",
                f"{id_types}:ToolDataAccess",
            ]
        )
        arg1 = ua.Variant("1:Length",ua.VariantType.String)
        arg2 = ua.Variant(258, ua.VariantType.Double)
        
        update_tool_data_method = await tool_data_methods.get_child([f"{id_types}:UpdateToolDataItems"])
        update_data = await tool_data_methods.call_method(
            update_tool_data_method,
            (arg1,arg2),
            ua.Variant(12, ua.VariantType.UInt32),
            ua.Variant(0, ua.VariantType.Byte)
        )
```

I get this error:

> BadInvaildArgument:One or more argument are invalid.

What I have tried is this:

```
        id_types = await client.get_namespace_index(config.NS_TYPES)
        id_core = await client.get_namespace_index(config.NS_CORE)
        machine = await client.nodes.objects.get_child(
            [f"{id_core}:HEIDENHAIN NC", f"{id_core}:Machine"])
        tool_data_methods = await machine.get_child(
            [
                f"{id_types}:ToolDataManagement",
                f"{id_types}:ToolDataAccess",
            ]
        )
        arg1 = ("1:Length")
        arg2 = ua.Variant(258, ua.VariantType.Double)
        arg3 = ua.KeyValuePair(arg1,arg2)
        update_tool_data_method = await tool_data_methods.get_child([f"{id_types}:UpdateToolDataItems"])
        update_data = await tool_data_methods.call_method(
            update_tool_data_method,
            (arg3),
            ua.Variant(12, ua.VariantType.UInt32),
            ua.Variant(0, ua.VariantType.Byte)
        )
```

I get this error:

> TypeError:must be called with a dataclass type or instance.

Can somebody give me a hint how to proceed KeyValuePair argument?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is a list so try this:

```
    id_types = await client.get_namespace_index(config.NS_TYPES)
    id_core = await client.get_namespace_index(config.NS_CORE)
    machine = await client.nodes.objects.get_child(
        [f"{id_core}:HEIDENHAIN NC", f"{id_core}:Machine"])
    tool_data_methods = await machine.get_child(
        [
            f"{id_types}:ToolDataManagement",
            f"{id_types}:ToolDataAccess",
        ]
    )
    arg1 = ("1:Length")
    arg2 = ua.Variant(258, ua.VariantType.Double)
    arg3 = [ua.KeyValuePair(arg1,arg2)]
    update_tool_data_method = await tool_data_methods.get_child([f"{id_types}:UpdateToolDataItems"])
    update_data = await tool_data_methods.call_method(
        update_tool_data_method,
        arg3,
        ua.UInt32(12),
        ua.Byte(0)
    )
```